# How to sandbox third party applications when `sandbox-exec` is deprecated now?

Tags: macos, security, sandbox, deprecated

I've noticed that in the newest MacOS the `sandbox-exec` command is deprecated. According to it's manual:

`The sandbox-exec command is DEPRECATED.  Developers who wish to sandbox an app should instead adopt the App Sandbox feature described in the App Sandbox Design Guide. [...]`

Moreover, a few commands were removed, like `sandbox-simplify`. Also, it seems that the trace function is not working anymore, the following config just does not produce output anymore (while it did in earlier versions):

```lisp
(version 1) 
(debug all)
(trace "/tmp/trace.sb")
(deny default)
```

My question is, what is the "new" way of sandboxing third-party apps? I'm not asking this question from the perspective of a developer. I'm asking it as a power user who wants to add additional sandboxing limits to apps I don't trust.

Comment: have you been able to find the answer to this? I am trying to do the same thing, but haven't been able to

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While Apple claims this older style of sandboxing via profiles (sometimes called "Seatbelt") is deprecated, it's still used heavily across macOS by both Apple and third-party developers as of 2020. You can find sandboxing profiles in various places such as:

- `/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles` for various macOS system components
- [Firefox's content process profile](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/security/sandbox/mac/SandboxPolicyContent.h)
- [Chrome's renderer process profile](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:services/service_manager/sandbox/mac/renderer.sb)

The new approach is the similarly-named [App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox) feature (more details in the [design guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/)). This newer sandboxing is controlled by "entitlements", which are various flags an app developer can set as part of the code signature when building the app. Internally, it makes use of the older sandboxing profile system above by applying the profile `/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/application.sb` during app startup. App Sandbox is much more limited than the full profile system, relying only on a few flags and lists, which can't offer the same flexibility as using profiles directly. As far as I know, there's no way to control this newer system as a user, since you'd needed repackage and resign an app to do so.

As a user, sandboxing profiles for `sandbox-exec` are still your main and only option on macOS. While it may say deprecated, it doesn't look like they are going away any time soon either, since it's still widely used in both profile form and as an internal layer for the newer App Sandbox feature.

Comment: Is there someplace to find `sandbox-simplify` so we can easily create our own profiles?

Comment: @JonathanCross Ah, not sure about that unfortunately, as I assume it's not available from Apple's [open source archive](https://opensource.apple.com). The best I can think of would be copying it from an older version, but unsure whether it would still run.

Comment: I just stumbled upon [a blog post](https://saagarjha.com/blog/2020/05/20/mac-app-store-sandbox-escape/) on this topic, part of which clarifies that the newer App Sandbox actually functions by loading a profile as well, so I have edited my answer to clarify the link between the two.